# Can Gibberish be a Modifier?

Tags: nouns, modifiers

For example, is the phrase "a gibberish language" grammatically correct? Since gibberish is a noun, is there a best way to tell if it is able to modify another noun?

Comment: I would say it's legitimate.  It's called a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct), and apparently several other things, depending on your religion.

Comment: I bet you encountered this while playing online games. Seen and used it many times.

Comment: I've known some folks who write gibberish code , even though they're not gibbering fools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Gibberish* actually shows up as adjective meaning unintelligible in [*The Century dictionary and cyclopedia: a work of universal reference*](https://books.google.com/books?id=e3lEAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA2508&dq=%22gibberish%20language%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjM7cjQ3O_QAhXMMSYKHfFCAowQ6AEINTAF#v=onepage&q=%22gibberish%20language%22&f=false) with a quote from *The Virgin Martyr*, a 1622 tragedy by Thomas Dekker and Philip Massinger:

> Physicians but torment him, his disease
>   Laughs at their ***gibberish*** language.

(*Italics*, *The Century*; **emphasis**, mine).

Modern usage allows the same. From [*Forbidden Region*](https://books.google.com/books?id=sZZ8qV04O6AC&q=%22gibberish%20language%22&dq=%22gibberish%20language%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiE8qzE3u_QAhXM6yYKHaDWBYsQ6AEIJDAC) (1991) by David North:

> He feigned interest as the five men and women talked incessantly in an
>   almost-**gibberish language** about gigabytes and multifile servers,
>   but he was on the alert.